# Center aligned grid list in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I wanted to get a center aligned grid list in Angular Material.

This is my code:

```html
<md-content layout-padding>
   <md-grid-list md-cols-gt-md="10" md-cols-md="8" md-cols-sm="6" md-cols="4" md-cols-xs="3"  md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="1:1" md-row-height-xs="110px" md-gutter-gt-md="10px" md-gutter="2px">
      <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="item in homeTilesNavigation">
         <div class="compas-home-text">{{item.name}}</div>
      </md-grid-tile>
   </md-grid-list>
</md-content>
```

I am getting a result like this:
[image: THAT]

But I wanted like this:
[image: This]

I wanted the same grid list to be center aligned.
Here is the [fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/d8zsoed8/13/).

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: PLease check this fiddle:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/d8zsoed8/13/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

Make your parent (i.e. `md-grid-list`) a flex container using `display: flex` & use `justify-content: center` to align its children (i.e. `md-grid-tile`) horizontally center. Like:

```
md-grid-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I've used `div`'s instead of regular `md-` type components for demonstration:

- **`md-grid-list`** is equivalent to `.list`
- **`md-grid-tile`** is equivalent to `.tile`

Have a look at the example snippet below (updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8zsoed8/16/) according to your requirements):

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="tile">
    <div class="compas-home-text">Grid Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile">
    <div class="compas-home-text">Grid Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile">
    <div class="compas-home-text">Grid Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile">
    <div class="compas-home-text">Grid Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile">
    <div class="compas-home-text">Grid Title</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tile">
    <div class="compas-home-text">Grid Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @VinuDeveloper Angular Material is overwriting the styles heavily, still I've updated the fiddle code & make it according to your requirements - https://jsfiddle.net/d8zsoed8/16/ . Also don't forgot to accept this as your answer, if this helped you out.